# MySQL, HAVING returns single result

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, having

I'm faced with a table of player which looks like so:

image of table here:
[image: image of table here]

I'm trying to return the players who play for an above average total playing time, I tried using WHERE in place of HAVING but I got a syntax error. My code just returns one player as opposed to all of the ones that play over the average total playing time:

```
SELECT player.player_name, player.player_team, player.minutes_played 
     FROM player 
         HAVING player.minutes_played > AVG(player.minutes_played);
```

Why does it return just one? Is it the nature of HAVING?

Comment: Don’t post an image.  Bring the relevant info here in text

Comment: HAVING is intended to be used with  GROUP BY - why don’t you just use WHERE?  Share the error you get - that’s the way to go based on what you have shared

Comment: The reason I'm using HAVING as opposed to HAVING is due to Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function. I think the reason I got that error is because you cannot use WHERE on an aggregated function (such as using AVG()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want looks like this:

```
SELECT p.player_name, p.player_team, p.minutes_played 
FROM player p
HAVING p.minutes_played > (SELECT AVG(p2.minutes_played) FROM player p2);
```

What is happening with your query?  Well, first I should note that the issue is `AVG(minutes_played)` rather than the `HAVING` clause *per se*.  MySQL has an extension where a `HAVING` clause is essentially treated as a `WHERE` -- for a query with no aggregations.

But, your query has aggregations.  It has the `AVG()` in the `HAVING` clause.  This turns the query into an aggregation query and because there is no `GROUP BY`, the query returns exactly one row (not counting the `HAVING`).

This begs the question of what values are in that one row.  Well, columns from *arbitrary* and *indeterminate* rows are returned.  This is also a MySQL extension.

The query that you have written is not standard SQL, but it is accepted in MySQL due to two extensions.  In doing so, the query is an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY`, so the query returns one row (or perhaps zero rows if the `HAVING` condition is not met).

Comment: Well this seemed to work - thank you for your additional explanation @Gordon Linoff! GROUP BY doesn't _seem_ to be required to get more than one query back, contrary to your comment. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by arbitrary and indeterminate rows are returned, why is this a MySQL extension? Would this code not work in other RDBMSs?

Comment: @will.i.may.be . . . This code would not work in other databases.